# How do I use LAST_INSERT_ID() in WebMatrix

Tags: .net, mysql, webmatrix, last-insert-id

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for a MySQL database in WebMatrix. Can someone show me how to apply it to the code snippet below?

```
var clothingsize="";
if(IsPost){     
clothingsize =Request["clothingsize"];         

var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO fit1 (clothingsize) VALUES (@0)"; }
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Typical SO - some idiot votes your question down because they don't understand it. See here instead: http://forums.asp.net/t/1752458.aspx/1?How+do+I+use+LAST_INSERT_ID+in+Webmatrix+to+connect+the+tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that works:

Right after this code on the signup page

```
db.Execute(SQLINSERT, fname, lname);
```

Add these 2 lines of code:

```
var customer_info_user_id = db.GetLastInsertId(); 
Response.Redirect("~/fit.cshtml?customer_info_user_id=" + customer_info_user_id);
```

Then insert the following into the subsequent pages:

Before the var to open the database

```
var customer_info_user_id = Request["customer_info_user_id"];
```

Add the id number that's been carried over into the INSERT functions. For example:

```
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO fit (customer_info_user_id, clothingsize) VALUES (@0,@1)";                  
db.Execute(SQLINSERT, customer_info_user_id, clothingsize);
```

Carry over the id number to the next page

```
Response.Redirect("~/flatter.cshtml?customer_info_user_id=" + customer_info_user_id);
```

Thanks to @Mike Brind and the ASP.net forum for helping me figure this out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you're using the MySQL .NET Connector?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

If so, here's a pretty simple example of what you're looking for:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,98672,98868#msg-98868

> After executing your Insert-Command (C#, Connection is stored in
>   conDBConnection):

```
> string strSQLSelect = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'LastID'"; 
> MySqlCommand dbcSelect = new MySqlCommand(strSQLSelect,
> conDBConnection);  MySqlDataReader dbrSelect =
> dbcSelect.ExecuteReader(); 
> 
> dbrSelect.Read();  int intCounter =
> Int32.Parse(dbrSelect.GetValue(0).ToString()); 
> 
> dbrSelect.Dispose();  conDBConnection.Close();
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I'm not using the Connector, but I think that Mike just answered my question :-)